# ¿Es en algún caso obligatorio escribir una cifra en números romanos en español?

Tags: ortografía, historia, rae, números

Recuerdo cuando era pequeño que los programas de televisión escribían el número del año en el que estaba grabado el programa en números romanos (se solía ver al final del programa, igual que hoy día). A partir de algún momento esa cifra pasó a ser escrita en número arábigos. Por ejemplo, se podía ver que un programa era (c) MCMXCII en vez de (c) 1992.

Igualmente, es común escribir los siglos en números romanos, pero no sé si es más una tradición que una imposición. Así, se dice que algo ocurrió en el siglo XIII más que en el siglo 13.

¿Ha dictado la RAE alguna norma que diga que los números romanos sean de uso obligatorio a la hora de escribir algún tipo de dato concreto? Me vale conocer las reglas en la actualidad, pero si se da algún tipo de contexto histórico para conocer si fueron de uso obligatorio en el pasado, aun mejor.

Comment: Lo pongo como comentario porque no tengo nada que añadir: [números romanos](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=QHaq7I8KrD6FQAyXTS#3) en el DPD. Parece que únicamente es obligatorio en los siglos y aunque no lo dice explicitamente en nombres de papas y reyes.

Comment: @blonfu tu comentario bien puede ser una respuesta. En todo caso, debemos recordar que el DPD es de 2005, mientras que la última ortografía es de 2010 y la última gramática de 2009-2011. Algunas cosas pueden haber variado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el DPD el único caso en el que es obligatorio el uso de los números romanos es al escribir los siglos:

> No deben usarse, en este caso, números arábigos: <sup>(x)</sup>*siglo 21* .

En otros casos solo se pueden usar números arábigos o ambos. Y luego está el caso de reyes, emperadores y papas en el que no se dice explícitamente si pueden usarse números arábigos o no pero sería extraño (yo al menos nunca lo he visto).

@CarlosAlejo comenta que el DPD es de 2005 y por tanto ha podido cambiar algo desde entonces. He buscado también en *Ortografia de la lengua española (2010)* y las normas en el uso de los números romanos [siguen igual](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QGBgBhUzBTpjPSAj) aunque se añaden algunos casos:

[image: Uso números romanos: punto b]

[image: Uso números romanos: punto j y k]

En esos casos tampoco queda claro si pueden usarse números arábigos aunque en las carreteras nacionales hay de los dos tipos como *N-III o N-102*; he encontrado hasta la *N-VI* en números romanos, el resto son arábigos.

Comment: Te añado el enlace a la página con que ilustras tu respuesta. Ahí se ve, efectivamente, que los usos no han cambiado, pero se comentan algunos más que no vienen en el DPD, como el usarlos para la escala Mercalli de intensidad de terremotos y para los números de las carreteras nacionales (N-IV), usos para los que no se comenta que se puedan usar números arábigos.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Cierto, no había visto la página siguiente donde aparecen esos dos casos nuevos. También añade las publicaciones periódicas en el punto **b)**

Comment: "*luego está el caso de reyes, emperadores y papas en el que no se dice explícitamente si pueden usarse números arábigos o no pero sería extraño*" Tal vez más que extraño sería confuso, "Felipe 5" no se si es un rey o la quinta parte de una película de boxeo.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster es curioso que digas eso ya que la quinta parte de la película de boxeo mas famosa es  con números romanos. Rocky V podía ser entonces el 5° con ese nombre de una estirpe de reyes o emperadores xD.

Comment: Esa era la broma @blonfu ;)